# Can we add back track tools to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, security, install-from-source, tools

If possible, then how can I add the tools available under **[Back Track Linux](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/)** to my Ubuntu 12.04 distribution. I prefer their functionality from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you can, It is not really advisable. Please refer to [this link](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#Why_cant_I_just_add_the_Backtrack_repositories_to_my_Ubuntu_install_or_the_Ubuntu_repositories_to_my_Backtrack_install_.3F) from the official back track website.